# Need to update a column of dataframe based on duplicate values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

This is a quick example of the problem :

I have the following dataframe :

```
data = {'name': ["name_1", "name_2" , "name_3" , "name_2" , "name_1" , "name_2" , "name_2" ], 'col_B': ["a", "a" , "a" , "b" , "a" , "c" , "a" ] , 'col_C' : [1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 5 , 6 , 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

df # Would give the following df below :
     name col_B  col_C
0  name_1     a      1
1  name_2     a      1
2  name_3     a      1
3  name_2     b      1
4  name_1     a      5
5  name_2     c      6
6  name_2     a      1
```

What I need is to check the combination name + col_B and for the duplicates, col_C -> 0. For example :

```
     name col_B  col_C
0  name_1     a      1
1  name_2     a      1
2  name_3     a      1
3  name_2     b      1
4  name_1     a      0
5  name_2     c      6
6  name_2     a      0
```

For that I created the following :

```
list_tst = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():

   if (row['name']+row['col_B'] in list_tst): 
      row['col_C'] = 0  # If already in the list set value to zero ( it's a duplicate )
   list_tst.append(row['name']+row['col_B']) # if not unique then add to list, could be inside 'else'
```

But as expected this takes too long to run with millions of rows. 
Could somebody please provide a suggestion to use vectorization for this?

Thanks!

Full Code :

```
import pandas as pd


data = {'name': ["name_1", "name_2" , "name_3" , "name_2" , "name_1" , "name_2" , "name_2" ], 'col_B': ["a", "a" , "a" , "b" , "a" , "c" , "a" ] , 'col_C' : [1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 5 , 6 , 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

list_tst = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():

   if (row['name']+row['col_B'] in list_tst):
      row['col_C'] = 0
   list_tst.append(row['name']+row['col_B'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it `mask` on `duplicated`:

```
df['col_C'].mask(df.duplicated(['name','col_B']),0)
```

Output:

```
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    0
5    6
6    0
Name: col_C, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be fast `cumcount` with `groupby`

```
df.col_C*=df.groupby(['name','col_B']).cumcount().eq(0)
df
     name col_B  col_C
0  name_1     a      1
1  name_2     a      1
2  name_3     a      1
3  name_2     b      1
4  name_1     a      0
5  name_2     c      6
6  name_2     a      0
```